# How do I re-sign .exe application? Need steps to generate .xml and certificate

Tags: visual-studio, signtool, makecert, makeappx

I have customising my version of the Ammyy Admin executable (AA_V3.exe) available from http://ammyy.com. I have bought a license that allows me to customise this file which I have successfully done. I am still getting an unsigned application window when opening on my 64 bit Windows 10 computer, and would like to resign this executable.

I have installed Visual Studio Community 2017 to get the signtool.exe. It seems I need to generate a certificate using makecert.exe, however to do this I need to be able to provide the Identity from the .xml file as outlined on this page - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj835832(v=vs.85).aspx. The issue is that there is no .xml file, nor can I seem to be able to get makeappx.exe generate one for me.

So as I see it, the steps I need to be able to complete are as follows;

1. Generate a .xml file from AA_V3.exe somehow using makeappx.exe
2. Find the Identity string for AA_V3 within that .xml file and then use makecert.exe to generate a certificate.
3. Use signtool to sign the AA_V3.exe application using my newly created certificate.

Let me know if I'm on the wrong track here.

Comment: You probably need to buy a proper certificate before Windows is happy.